# Constructive proof of Closest Point Theorem in Convex Optimization

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, alternative-proof

I have seen the closest point theorem for convex subsets (for example https://www.tutorialspoint.com/convex_optimization/convex_optimization_closest_point_theorem.htm). Nevertheless, I am looking for a constructive proof. Does anyone know about any constructive proof for this?

Comment: Depending on what you're willing to assume about the convex set $C$, there are algorithms that will produce a sequence of points converging to the projection of a given point onto the nearest point in $C$.  Would such an algorithm satisfy you?